# Inputs aren't working on iOs emulator

Tags: native-base

I've executed the [NativeBase-KitchenSink](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink) demo on iOs emulator, but all the input fields aren't working neither the keyboard. Look the follow screens:

[image: Floating Label]

[image: Underline TextBox]

[image: Rounded TextBox]

Is there needed adding custom style? And do I have to implement keyboard rules?

My versions

- Node: v7.3.0
- native-base: 2.1.0
- react-native: 0.42.3

Comment: What version of [NativeBase KitchenSink](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink) did you try with? I never faced such

Comment: Hi! The version is 2.1.0. Thanks for replying me.

Comment: Have you installed any other package with KitchenSink? or upgraded any of its versions?